# Вынести некоторые технологии из ответа в отдельный вопрос

Tags: предложение, книги-сообщества

На ruSO есть вопрос [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/275232) и в данном вопросе вставлены ресурсы и справочники не только по Java, но и околоJava технологий:

- Hibernate
- Spring
- Swing
- JavaFX

Я считаю, что данные технологии надо убрать из ответа, вынести их в отдельные вопросы и прикрепить сделать ссылку на них в [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/275232). К примеру, создать вопрос: `Справочники и ресурсы по GUI на Java`. Чтобы я туда написал? Ссылки на сайты, книги, статьи по Java Swing, JavaFX и другие GUI-технологии.

В отдельный вопрос я бы вынес Spring, Hibernate и JavaEE.

**Почему так стоит сделать?**

1. Если человек ищет через поисковик `Справочник по Spring` или `Справочник по веб-разработке на Java` и он видит `Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java`, я не думаю, что он нажмет и прокрутит вниз до ответа.
2. Разрузить количество ресурсов/справочников в ответе.
3. В ответе представлены не все ресурсы, что собственно нормально, но вы представьте сколько книг существует по Spring, Hibernate, JavaEE? Только одного Spring я прочитал 6-7 книг, просмотрел десятки **полезных ресурсов** (http://baeldung.com/, https://spring.io/, ...). Уверен, данные технологии заслуживают существовать отдельно.

**P.S.**
В случае, если идея будет одобрена, могу ли я создать вопросы, приведенные выше, чтобы они модернизироваться Java-коммьюнити на ruSO? Также, я готов принять активное участие в развитие данных вопросов.

*Убедительная просьба! Если есть вопросы - задайте их в комментарии, прежде чем минусовать*

Comment: Мне кажется, имеет смысл сначала добавить источники в общий ответ, а потом уже думать, нужно ли выделять отдельные технологии или нет.

Comment: @insolor источники в тех ответах есть, если вы спрашиваете о Hibernate, Spring, Swing, JavaFX. Просто можно те источники перенести в отдельный вопрос/ответ, а в начале сообщения сделать ссылку на те вопросы.

Comment: Я к тому, что в текущем виде по каждой упомянутой технологии 3-5 источника. Мне кажется, ради этого их выносить в отдельные вопросы-ответы не имеет смысла. P.S. хотя в отдельный вопрос по GUI фреймворкам, думаю, можно

Comment: @insolor Кстати, я имею право сам создавать вопросы на подобии `Справочники и ресурсы по GUI на Java`? Уверен, что многие пользователи ruSO посчитают это дубликатом, хотя это не так

Comment: @insolor На самом деле их больше и ответ давно глобально не обновлялся.

Comment: Вот я и предлагаю, сначала обновить существующий ответ, чтобы было что обсуждать)

Comment: @insolor понял Вас!

Comment: С третьим пунктом всё просто: не нужно добавлять в ответ все существующие книги и ресурсы, только объективно лучшие и максимум пару. Мы же не каталог интернета сделать пытаемся.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Про каталог интернет каталог и не идет и речи. Если говорить о Spring, то и без меня Вы знаете, что у него множество направлений: от простого сайтика до сложных микросерверов. Уверен, на данную тему [Spring] точно найдется десяток полезных ресурсов.

Comment: @Antonio112009 знаю, что для изучения Spring вполне достаточно одного учебника. Для любой дальнейшей работы хватит документации.

Comment: @Antonio112009 и не совсем понятно, зачем вы добавили "Pro Spring 5", если его русский вариант уже есть?

Comment: @Antonio112009 почему baeldung.com именно в разделе Spring?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev про "Pro Spring 5" - я не знаю как будет данная книга на русском. Всю литературу читаю в оригинале

Comment: baeldung.com в основном затрагивает темы связанные со Spring (и Hibernate)

Comment: @Antonio112009 "Pro Spring 5" = "Spring 5 для профессионалов". Здесь всё-таки Stackoverflow **на русском**. Я считаю, что добавлять англоязычные книги стоит только в том случае, если нет сравнимых русскоязычных.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Как я сказал выше, я не знаю как будут называться книги в переводе на русский. Соглашусь только в том, что я не обратил внимания на авторов книги, где мог догадаться, что я дублирую описание одной и той же книги

Comment: @Antonio112009 к правкам каноничных ответов надо подходить ответственно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev как я понимаю, не смотря на то, что сайты связаны только со Spring/Hibernate, их стоит вынести в ответе в категорию `Онлайн-ресурсы`?

Comment: @Antonio112009 я бы так сделал.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev сейчас исправлю